# How do i drop all columns that include '_id' - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with 247 columns. Many of the column names contain "_id" in the column name. How do I drop all columns that contain "_id"??

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straight forward as well. Select the columns that contain "_id" and then invert it, use .loc to restrict the columns, and you're done.

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains("_id")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(like='_id')), axis = 1, inplace = True)]
```

What this code does is:
To filter all those columns which will have `_id` anywhere in its name and then dropping all those columns.

let me know if you didn't understand or need any help in this regard.

Comment: let me know if you need any other help in this regard. And if you find the answer useful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick mark(grey colored) on the left of the answer. And also upvote the answer. Thanks